Проблема при подключении через Shadow RDP в Доменной сети
Для администрирования пользователей в локальной сети использую теневое подключение (и пользовательская машина и моя находятся в домене). Используются windows 10 pro, windows 8 и windows 10 enterprise. Для подключения использую такую строку в консоли mstsc.exe /shadow:1 /v:(адрес либо доменное имя), также для определения id сессии qwinsta /server:(адрес либо доменное имя). При попытке определения id на удаленной машине выдаётся сообщение отказано в доступе. Ошибка 5. Для подключения пробовал как администратора в домене, так и локального. Для тестов на подключаемой машине отключен файервол. Как определить что мешает подключению?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
